# Div that should take up the "rest of the page" expands beyond the page in ie

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html, width

Okay, this is REALLY starting to bug me...
This page works fine in both Chrome and Firefox. [www.bloggan.tk](http://www.bloggan.tk)
But if it's opened in internet-explorer it always expands beyond the page and introduces the scrollbar no matter what the resolution of the browser is.
I have NO idea what change in the html it was that cause this...
Here's the [blogger-template-html-source](http://docs.google.com/Doc?docid=0Ae5lvtYm6WoBZGQ5cjU1cGNfNTdmOTk2NDlneg&hl=sv)

I'd REALLY appreciate if someone could help me with this.
Thanks in advance!

Edit:
I've "solved" it for IE using javascript, but that's only temporary (i hope). The version without javascript can be seen [here](http://www.weebly.com/uploads/3/8/1/8/3818197/brokenbloggan.htm), so that you still will be able to know what I'm talking about. Still trying to solve it, and still hoping for someone to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you ask a question here, you'll need to do some basic research yourself.

Strip out everything from that HTML file you reference until you have the simplest possible document that reproduces the error.  Don't expect people to dig through a 40k HTML file to find the thing that's causing you grief.

Isolate it before you ask about it.

Incidentally, however, there is no CSS width or height specifier for "the rest of the page".  You need to meticulously keep track of your percentage widths to make them add up to 100%, or use tables.  If your sample is using percentages, then I'd look for borders and padding, since those are the things that cause discrepancies in box size between old IE versions and modern browsers.